# Ionic Nav View changes controller on state change, but not view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Doing simple routing with Ionic and Ui-Router. When I tap the link that should change the view (anchor tag with ui-sref), the controller changes (which I can tell because things are being printed to the console) but nothing is injected into the view.

Here is the relevant code.

**APP.JS**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

$stateProvider.state('feed', {
   url: '/feed',
    views: {
      feed: {
        templateURL: '/../feed.html',
        controller: 'feedController'
      }
    }
  }) 
})
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">app</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <a ui-sref="feed">go to feed </a>
  <div ui-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="Feed"></ion-nav-view>
  </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

**FEED.HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Feed">
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="photo in media track by $index">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img ng-src={{photo.user.profile_picture}}>
        <h2> {{photo.user.username }}</h2>
        <p>{{photo.created_time | date:'HH:mm:ss Z'}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-image">
        <img ng-src={{photo.images.low_resolution.url}}>
      </div>

      <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-heart-outline"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble-outline"></i>
        </a>
     </div>


     <div class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-heart"></i>
      <span class="likes"> {{photo.likes.count}} likes </span>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
        <span> {{photo.user.username}}: {{photo.caption.text}} </span> 
     </div>
     <div class="item">
        <ul ng-repeat="comment in photo.comments.data">
            <li> {{comment.from.username}} {{comment.text}} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Don't use the `ui-view` as the `ion-nav-view` component is the correct one to wire up navigation in Ionic. Ionic extends ui-router to with features, and using the vanilla `ui-view` can muck with things.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from here : `templateURL: '/../feed.html',`

`templateUrl` starts from `www` folder so if you have the following structure :

```
project 
 - templates
    - feed.html
 - platforms
 - www
    - js
    - css
    - index.html
```

You shall use `templateURL: './../feed.html',`

But a proper structure defines the `templates` within the `www` folder

```
project 
  - platforms
  - www
    - templates
      - feed.html
    - js
    - css
    - index.html
```

and the follwoing routing : `templateURL: 'templates/feed.html',`

Moreover, HTML view Naming shall be in phase with ui-routing naming.
so for this configuration :

```
$stateProvider.state('feed', {
   url: '/feed',
    views: {
      feed: {
        templateURL: '/../feed.html',
        controller: 'feedController'
      }
    }
  }) 
})
```

you shall have

```
    <ion-nav-view name="feed"></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: Nope, no change. Thanks though!

Comment: into html you defined : name="Feed" and in your routing :  views: { feed: { ...}} . Update HTML or JS to have the same naming

Comment: changed that, but sadly still no change :(

Comment: I don't have <div ui-view> </div> also ;)

Comment: OK—took out <div ui-view> as well. Still seeing nothing, but getting logs from the controller in the Console

Comment: do you get the title change "FEED" ?

Comment: Yup, any reference to the word 'feed' is spelled as 'feed'

Comment: I mean : <ion-view title="Feed"> do you see the title of your page changed to that one ?

Comment: No, the title doesn't change.

Comment: There for it comes from your index.html ;) that is not well structure. 
Why don't you start from a blank project that let you have that already configured ? for exemple : ionic strat myApp tabs

Comment: I'd really like to keep going with what I have here, considering I'm integrating a lot of pre-written angular code. Thank you for your help though, I will take a look at some of the sample apps.